# Pearl's Causal Inference In Statistics: Study Question 1.5.1

Tags: regression, expected-value, linear, causality

**Problem Statement:** Suppose we have the following Structural Causal Model (SCM). Assume all exogenous variables ($U$) are independent identically distributed standard normals. 
\begin{align*}
V&=\{X,Y,Z\},\qquad U=\{U_X, U_Y, U_Z\},\qquad F=\{f_X, f_Y, f_Z\}\\
f_X: X&=U_X\\
f_Y: Y&=\frac{X}{3}+U_Y\\
f_Z: Z&=\frac{Y}{16}+U_Z.
\end{align*}
Determine the best guess of $Y,$ given that we observed $X=1$ and $Z=3.$
[Hint: you may wish to use the technique of multiple regression, together with the fact that, for
every three normally distributed variables, say $X, Y,$ and $Z,$ we have
$E[Y|X=x,Z=z]=R_{Y\!X\cdot Z}x+R_{Y\!Z\cdot X}z.$]

**My Answer:** We assume the model
$$Y=\alpha+\beta_XX+\beta_ZZ+\varepsilon,$$
with $\beta_X$ and $\beta_Z$ given by
\begin{align*}
\beta_X=R_{Y\!X\cdot Z}
&=\frac{\sigma_Z^2\sigma_{Y\!X}-\sigma_{Y\!Z}\sigma_{Z\!X}}{\sigma_X^2\sigma_Z^2-\sigma_{X\!Z}^2}\\
\beta_Z=R_{Y\!Z\cdot X}
&=\frac{\sigma_X^2\sigma_{Y\!Z}-\sigma_{Y\!X}\sigma_{X\!Z}}{\sigma_Z^2\sigma_X^2-\sigma_{Z\!X}^2}.
\end{align*}
Now here's where things get a little hazy. Going off the model, and the idea that if $C=aA+bB,$ then $\sigma_C^2=a^2\sigma_A^2+b^2\sigma_B^2,$ we have the following equations:
\begin{align*}
\sigma_X^2&=\sigma_{U_X}^2=1\\
\sigma_Y^2&=\frac19 \sigma_X^2+\sigma_{U_Y}^2=\frac{10}{9}\\
\sigma_Z^2&=\frac{1}{256}\sigma_Y^2+\sigma_{U_Z}^2=\frac{1157}{1152}.
\end{align*}
Here's where I have trouble: computing the covariances. I know that, for example,
$$\sigma_{XY}=E(XY)-\underbrace{E(X)}_{=0}E(Y)=E(XY)$$
in this case, since $E(X)=0.$ Then I substitute in to obtain
\begin{align*}
E(XY)
&=E(X(X/3+U_Y))\\
&=\frac13 E\big(X^2\big)+\underbrace{E(XU_Y)}_{=0}\\
&=\frac13\left(\sigma_X^2-(E(X))^2\right)\\
&=\frac13.
\end{align*}
A similar calculation reveals that
\begin{align*}
\sigma_{XZ}&=\frac{1}{48}\\
\sigma_{YZ}&=\frac{5}{72}.
\end{align*}

> My question is: are these calculations correct so far? If so, I think I can make my way to the end by plugging into the expressions above for the regression coefficients, and then the model.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Just for my edification, what does the notation $R_{YX \cdot Z}x$ means?

Comment: Sure! $R_{YX\cdot Z}$ means the slope of $Y$ on $X$ when we hold $Z$ constant; it's also known as a partial regression coefficient. See *Causal Inference in Statistics: A Primer*, p. 23.

Comment: Got it, thanks! So, question then. Shouldn't the formula be $E[Y|X,Z]=y_0+R_{YX \cdot Z}x+R_{YZ \cdot X}z$ where $y_0=E[Y|X=0,Z=0]$?

Comment: Well, the formula I typed up in the hint is exactly what Pearl has. If you notice in my answer, I allow an offset such as you suggest. In the context of this problem, I doubt it matters, as I think the $y_0$ you've got there would be zero, given that the exogenous variables are all standard normals.

Comment: Ah, yes, good point. I did not consider that - I suppose, in general, its just an offset. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was, indeed, on the right track. To finish the calculations:
\begin{align*}
\sigma_X^2&=1\\
\sigma_Y^2&=10/9\\
\sigma_Z^2&=1157/1152\\
\sigma_{XY}&=1/3\\
\sigma_{YZ}&=5/72\\
\sigma_{XZ}&=1/48\\ \\
E[Y|X=1,Z=3]&=400/771.
\end{align*}

Comment: Might a bit late, but this result also concurs with mine. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that given that $X=1$, then $E(X)$ should be 1, not 0. I understand the confusion once $X=U_x$ and $E(U_x)=0$. But the previous only state that the value of $X$ is caused by the value of $U_x$, in this case the value of X is already observed to be 1, hence a constant $c$, and because $E(c)=c$ then $E(X)=1$.
$E(Y|X=1)=E(1/3 +U_y)=1/3$.

Note that $\sigma_{xy}=0$ does not imply that X and Y are independent.